# Should I replace this siding?

Tags: water, siding

I bought this house with a washer/dryer in the basement (on carpet!) and had it moved to the garage. The dryer vent was letting in water, also.

I've put up siding on a new house before, but I wanted to ask for advice on this project.

[image: siding]

Is it enough to seal the holes, sand and repaint this part of the siding? Or do I need to rip it out and replace the siding?

Comment: Spend the time sanding and repainting or the money on new siding.  Almost equal if time and money are.  I don't see any major damage expect the paint, sanding those grooves won't be fun.  Paint prep is about 90% of the paint job.  New siding might be able to go right on top, no ripping off needed.

Comment: What about my duct taped dryer vent hole? Is there a good sealant or something I should use to make sure it doesn't let water in?

Comment: If start to sand and find rot that changes things.

Comment: Wood glue and the right size wood patch to fit in, or cut the hole to the wood patch.  You are painting over it and just siding so not as important

Comment: Love the taped over hole.   Smoothing out the tape like that shows a true artisan worked on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your siding simply needs a good scraping and sanding. If you want to go over the top, use a heat gun to remove the old paint to get back down to bare wood, use a mask when getting into this.

There is nothing that says the siding is bad. The old hole duct taped over that can be filled in, or if you are adventurous, temporarily remove the hose bib and replace the lower board. Be careful, it may be tongue and groove, and it would be very possible to damage the siding above if the groove of the next piece up is broken off.